# How do I approach calculating an optimal sample size for injecting mice for triggering an immune response?

Tags: sample-size, effect-size, fishers-exact-test, ratio

Hypothetical: there is a research team tasked with injecting mice aimed at triggering a specific immune response to produce monoclonal antibodies (MAb). Up until now, they've been largely unsuccessful in trials involving mice counts of 3 or 6. There have only been 6 total trials and only 1 trial (using a very specific hapten/protein chain) has been successful. Therefore, the archive of historical data on this specific experiment is sparse. To calculate a very conservative sample size, I'm assuming the historical immune response rate is 0% (largely because there are categorical factors here that I'm ignoring for the time being).

I'm wondering if I can apply Fisher's Exact Test to this problem in an effort to calculate the sample size necessary to detect an alternative response rate of 5% or 10% in the mice subjects. The research team considers the outcome to be a binomial; either the mouse produces antibodies or it doesn't. I have an initial proportion (P1), a desired proportion (P2) of 5% or 10%, default values for alpha and beta, and an allocation ratio of 1. As far as I know, these are all the input parameters needed to compute sample size for Fisher's Exact Test.

My concern is if I am applying the concept of the problem accordingly. This is very much trailblazing work, so it's assumed that a "best educated guess" is acceptable in this case.